# mySQL IF column contains specific data, display that column, else display another column

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I want to create a query that, based on the data, can display one of three columns.

I have three date columns: Date1, Date2, Date3. If Date1 is not equal to '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND is smaller than "<" NOW(), display that column. If both of these values aren't satisfied, then look at Date2 for the same query. If that isn't satisfied then look at Date3.

Here's the syntax I tried piecing together:

```
SELECT ID, Type, Status, IF (Date1 <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND < NOW() THEN Date1 ELSEIF Date2 <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND < NOW() THEN Date2 ELSEIF Date3 <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND < NOW() THEN Date3) AS col1 FROM tableA
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `IF THEN ELSEIF` like that in a query. You are looking for `CASE`:

```
SELECT ID, Type, Status,
    (CASE
        WHEN Date1 <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND Date1 < NOW()
            THEN Date1
        WHEN Date2 <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND Date2 < NOW()
            THEN Date2
        WHEN Date3 <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND Date3 < NOW()
            THEN Date3
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS col1
FROM tableA
```